# Autorotation doesn't work

Tags: ios5, storyboard, autorotate

I have a code in each view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

also I changed supported device orientations in a plist.

What else could it be?

P.S. As I checked — notifications about rotation not sends anymore. Probably there is a conflict with some framework...

Comment: No :) I tested on both device and simulator

Comment: on the interface builder, did you make sure that both of your controllers have the orientation "inferred"?

Comment: Yes, it stands "inferred" there

Comment: you should describe what type of project you have. It's very unclear what may cause this issue

Comment: @mancunianetz Can you please clarify what information? I use iOS5 ARC project, universal app with storyboards — I used tags to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out [Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html)

And one remark, do not modify device orientations from plist, there is another way , select project , then Summary tab and then in Supported Device Orientations choose that you need. This way will automatically edit your plist.